# How to access the Array field in the Json Object?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, json, rest

So I have a Json object `FriendJson` and in it I have a array field `friends`.

Json Object:

```
[
  {
    "id": 4,
    "updated": "2023-01-07T22:06:23.929206Z",
    "created": "2023-01-07T19:49:49.303182Z",
    "user": 35,
    "friends": [
      36,
      37,
      38,
      39
    ]
  }
]
```

The question is how to access `friends` array and traverse it. I am using react so I need to use `map()` for traversal. I am trying this in return part of a Functional component, so can use much functionalities of Javascript.

My component:

```
import React, {useContext, useEffect, useRef, useState} from 'react'
import { useNavigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import AlertContext from '../context/Alerts/AlertContext';
import FriendContext from '../context/Friends/FriendContext';
import FriendItem from './FriendItem'

export default function YourFriends() {

  const {friendJson, getFriends, addFriend, getUserId, getReceiverId} = useContext(FriendContext)
  const {showAlert} = useContext(AlertContext)

  const navigate = useNavigate()

  useEffect (() => {
    if(localStorage.getItem('authToken')) {
      getFriends()
    }
    else navigate('/signin')
  })



  return (
    <>
      <div className="container">
        <h2 className="text-center">Your Friends</h2>
        {
          friendJson.length === 0 && <div className="text-conter">You don't have any friends</div>
        }
        {
          // console.log(friendJson.friends)
          friendJson.friends.map((eachFriend) => {
            return <FriendItem key={eachFriend} friend={eachFriend}/>
          }) 
        }
      </div>
    </>
  )
}
```

I tried in this way:

```
friendJson.friends.map((eachFriend) => {
     return <FriendItem key={eachFriend} friend={eachFriend}/>
})
```

But it throws error as:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')
```

And when I `console.log(FriendJons.friends)` the result is `undefined`.

Comment: Try to access the friends list like this: `FriendJson[0].friends` 
Your FriendJson is an array of objects, in this case 1 object, then you have the friends property.

Comment: From the given JSON, it looks like `friendJson` is, itself, an array, so you will have to either loop through it or get its first element, in order to get access to the inner `friends` array.

Comment: @Haroldo_OK Yeah but I cannot use loop right there, that's the problem

Comment: @JuljoShahini not working..

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)

Comment: @LoveS that was one of the issues I noticed, also check this: `https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-panka-iu58q9?file=/src/App.js`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your `FriendJson` is an array you should go to friends by

```
FriendJson[0].friends
```

rather than

```
FriendJson.friends
```

potentially you can iterate ofer `FriendJson` and in any of his elements get `friends`.

```
friendJson.map((element) => {
  return element.friends.map((eachFriend) => {
     return <FriendItem key={eachFriend} friend={eachFriend}/>
  })
})
```

---

general rule for errors like "Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'map')"

is print object having property on which you need to read "map" in your case if this solution will not work then check what is `friendJson`.

Comment: Thank you it worked, but I didn't get the intuition though

Comment: ```FriendJson[0].friends.map((eachFriend) => {... })``` Why is this not working and giving ```TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'friends')```??

Comment: @LoveS It's because `FriendJson` is an array; the `FriendJson` array does not contain an attribute `friends`; the object inside that outermost array is that has those attributes. So, you need to either get the first element of the outermost array, or loop through the outermost array, in order to get the said object.

Comment: Then how to directly access the ```object inside that outermost array```? How to do it in my example without outer ```map()``` in your answer? Is there any other way, just want to know because I want to learn

Comment: There does not seem to be much alternative here: it would either be necessary to use the first element of the array, or use some form of looping/iterating the outer array, `map()` being the most fitting for that in this case.